# Variable value is not set by JavaScript Function

Tags: function, javascript

I have created a variable and tried to set its value by a function. But this value in not accessible outside that function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
   var pId;
   getProfiles(id,function(b)
     {
        pId=b;
        alert(pId); // It works fine...
      });
  alert(pId); // undefined...
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You are wrong pId is not global here. You must declare it outside $(document).ready() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first alert works because it is just after the value is set by the *callback* function you're passing to `getProfiles`.

The second alert in your code example still shows the value "undefined" because the *callback* function you are passing to getProfiles hasn't executed yet.

Also, just a side note: `pId` is local to the function you are passing to jQuery's ready event, it is not a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

You declare `pId` but you don't assign any value to it, so by default is `undefined`, the alert in the same scope is then evaluated, and prints '`undefined`'.
The anonymous function is a callback that is called by `getProfiles()` (maybe asynchronously), and you cannot assume that it will be called before the outer `alert` is called.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
   /* You declare it but you don't assign any value to it... 
    * so by default is undefined 
    */
   var pId; 
   getProfiles(id,function(b)
     {
        pId=b;
        alert(pId); // This is called only once your anonymous callback is called...
      });
  alert(pId); // Alerts 'undefined'
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you assign to `pId` new value without declaration variable pId declared in global scope. But you have a local `pId` variable. So when you call alert inside callback it show value of GLOBAL `pId` and you second alert show your LOCAL `pId` value.

```
function f() { d = 2; }; 
function a() {
    var d = 1;
    f();
    alert(d);
}
a();
alert(d);
```

First alert will show 1 and second will show 2. So second alert in you code will always show `undefined` no matter when callback called.